# add onchange attribute via jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following html snippet i need to add onchange = "namefunction(this)" to it once i replaced execute additional instructions

```html
    <select id="test-dropdown">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
```

**later**

```html
<select id="test-dropdown" onchange="namefunction(this)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample code to work with select and add a function using onchange:

```html
<select 
    id="test-dropdown" 
    onmousedown="this.value='';" 
    onchange="selectNumber(this.value);" >
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<script>
    function selectNumber(value) {
        alert(value);
        //add additional instructions with value
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add attribute with jQuery with simply `$('#test-dropdown').attr('onchange', 'namefunction(this)');`. Try it below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test-dropdown').attr('onchange', 'namefunction(this)');
});

function namefunction(el) {
  console.log(el.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test-dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer in the menstruation it works as indicated, when I do the test I get an error as in the following screenshothttps://prnt.sc/12gftuu

Comment: @user117732 put that whole `<script> $(document)...</script>` after select-box .

Comment: @user117732, `$` is object from `jquery` and you have write code before actually loading `jquery` so you are getting that error. Use it in the end of your html then it will work. Or at least it should appear after `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: Why in the world would you add an event listener with attr?